# Do wires and electrical boxes need to be protected on the un-finished side of basement?

Tags: electrical, wiring, receptacle, basement

I'm considering drywall cover some part of the wood frame on the unfinished side of the basement. The wires and electrical boxes are exposed as in the picture. Not sure if it is necessary.  I would appreciate your advice...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

No, but they do need to be secured to the framing according to the NEC schedule. You must staple (or otherwise restrain) within 12" of each box, and every four feet along framing members, centered on the board. By doing so you reduce the likelihood of cable damage due to snags and fastener penetration.

A neat wiring job involves straight, flat runs, gentle, consistent bends, and adequate stapling. For example:

[image]

Comment: +1 But there is a requirement to protect cables from damage, so if they are in an area that would subject them to being hit or tugged, a covering might be needed.

Comment: Wouldn't they also need to add the little metal cover plates where the wires run through the framing members?

Comment: Only where they're close to the surface. If you put your bores in the center of standard-size studs, they're not.

Comment: @bib I think that it's generally assumed that wiring inside wall cavities is relatively safe. Wiring on the surface of walls, beams, joists, etc. is in a different category.

Comment: How about using plywood board to cover up only the areas when the cables run ? is that going to be a fire hazard ?

Comment: No, using wood in a wall is not a fire hazard. :) You'll need to decide whether that's necessary. It looks like you might be planning a work area there. A backboard would be wise in that case.

Comment: Thanks, those twisted cables going into the sides of the panel will haunt my dreams.

Comment: The half-twist? That's the right way to go in my opinion.  Flat bends put a lot of stretch into the outer conductor.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider armor-clad wiring in this case. It may not be required, but it would ensure the exposed wiring won't be damaged (which would cost more in the long run). This is also safer, since you reduce the risk of shock. We have an unfinished attic where I work that adjoins a finished room. On the unfinished side all wiring is armored.

Comment: Armor-clad also the part of wire that pass through the studs ?

Comment: You would want to go to metal boxes and armor clad inside the studs, yes

Comment: To do that, do I replace the plastic outlet boxes with metal ?

Comment: Yes. You can buy metal boxes with armor clad clamps that should help the process long ([example](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Raco-1-Gang-Gray-Metal-Interior-New-Work-Old-Work-Deep-Switch-Outlet-Celing-Wall-Electrical-Box/3129395))

Comment: This answer suggests unnecessary work from a code standpoint: AC cable is subject to the same physical damage requirements as the current NM wiring.

Comment: Can you tell from the picture if there is anything that needs to be fixed or improved.  The area around the on-off wall switch.  Should there be more protection on the wire around there ?

Comment: @statueuphemism As I stated, it's not *required*, it just might be a good idea. Code is just a minimum level of safety

Comment: @Dennis Other than securing the wire to the stud it looks fine

Comment: @Machavity I wasn't knocking you for your answer, I just wanted to make sure Dennis understood it is not required since he was asking a number of questions related to how to do it. That said, I would opt to throw up some drywall before I would completely rewire with AC cable for protection from physical damage.